# Return JsonResult from WebApi not working ASP.NET

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, jsonresult

I have a MVC project. I want to get a simple json response {result: "ok"}. Below is my code

```
using System;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk;
using CRM_WebApp.Models;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.Cors;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Query;
using CRM_WebApp.Services;

namespace CRM_WebApp.Controllers
{
    [EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
    public class CallBackFormController : ApiController
    {

        [System.Web.Mvc.HttpPost]
        public JsonResult Post([FromBody] CallBackFormModel CallBackFormModel)
        {
            ConnectiontoCrm connectiontoCrm = new ConnectiontoCrm();
            //connectiontoCrm.GetConnectiontoCrm();
            connectiontoCrm.GetConnectiontoCrmCopy();

            Entity lead = new Entity("lead");
            lead["firstname"] = CallBackFormModel.FirstName;
            lead["mobilephone"] = CallBackFormModel.Telephone;
            lead["telephone3"] = CallBackFormModel.Telephone;

            Guid tisa_callbackformid = connectiontoCrm.organizationservice.Create(callbackform);
            return new JsonResult { Data = new { result = "ok" } };
        }
    }
}
```

My code gives me the following response:

```
{
    "ContentEncoding": null,
    "ContentType": null,
    "Data": {
        "result": "ok"
    },
    "JsonRequestBehavior": 1,
    "MaxJsonLength": null,
    "RecursionLimit": null
}
```

How can i change my code to get response: {result: "ok"}

Comment: Your result should be `{"result": "ok"}` as `{result: "ok"}` is invalid because string should be wrapped in double quote. Then no matter what the Json is, visual studio special copy past allow you to create the corresponding class. But here i's a bit 'overkill' for a one line json like this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

after some investigation in your code, I really noticed that there are some fundamental errors.

1. When you are Inheriting from `ApiController` so here you are creating WebApiController, not MVC controller (which could be created by inheriting from `Controller` class)
2. You have to be careful about the namespaces you use because there are some classes and attribute which has the same name but in different namespaces, for example, the `HttpPost` attribute exists in the `System.Web.Http` and the `System.Web.Mvc` and according to your code you have to use the one in the former namespace because you are inheriting from the `ApiController`.

Keep in mind that the `System.Web.Mvc` is for ASP.NET MVC and the `System.Web.Http` is for the Web API.

3. You are not using the correct return type for the method (which represent Web API method)

So after fixing all the previous problems, the working code should be like this

```
[System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
public System.Web.Http.IHttpActionResult Post([System.Web.Http.FromBody] CallBackFormModel CallBackFormModel)
{
    // your previous code goes here
    return Json(new { result = "ok" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

I recommend you to read about ASP.NET MVC and the Web API and the differences between them to avoid those kinds of problems in the future.

Comment: HI. I'm getting error: Argument 2: Cannot convert from System.Web.Mvc.JsonRequestBehavior to Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings

Comment: `return JsonResult(new {result = "ok"}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);`

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding **how** and **why** it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: @OscarDominguezNavarrete I updated the answer for you

Comment: @HakamFostok I tried your answer but unsuccessfully(( I'm getting the following error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Web.Http.Results.OkNegotiatedContentResult<<anonymous type: string result>>' to 'System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult'

Comment: @OscarDominguezNavarrete see the updated answer again

Comment: @HakamFostok Now all is working fine. Thank you for your detailed answer and recommendation. I already start to learn more about MVC and Web API controlleres

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
return Json(new { result = "ok" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Comment: I'm getting error: JsonResult does not contain a constructor that take 1 arguments

Answer (score 0):

To answer you question I had the same issues because when I return a response I like to return multiple objects/types.

For instance I always return a message result containing some success and error messages. This object is pretty much reused across all my api responses. I then like to return a second object containing any data such as a list of customers or whatever.

This is how I got it working for WebAPI...

```
public IHttpActionResult DeleteEmailTemplate(int id)
    {
        FormResponse formResponse = new FormResponse("SUCESS MESSAGE HERE");

        List<string> strings = new List<string>();
        strings.Add("this is a test");
        strings.Add("this is another test");

        return Json(new { MessageResult = formResponse, TestObject = strings });
    }
```